# Triangle Geometry Query

Tags: trigonometry, angle, points

I'm hoping someone can help me out.   My trigonometry is a bit rusty!

See link below.  I know all three coordinates and all three distances.    What I want to calculate are the coordinates of the red dot!

I'm hoping it might be an easy answer for a mathematician out there?

[Click here to see illustration of the triangle and required coordinate](http://www.bmdata.co.uk/angles.pdf)

Comment: Stack Overflow is for specific programming based questions.  Dumping a link to a homework problem isn't a good fit for SO.

Comment: Apologies - not enough information.

Comment: This is a geometry problem related to a d3.js force graph.

Comment: The coordinates are the points of a node and the distances are the fixed distance for each link.

Comment: I need the red point because I want these particular node links to join on the outer radius of the circle node not the center.

Comment: Either way the calculations remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

If triangle is isosceles:

Find bisector vector, normalize it, take vector with length d3 from (X3,Y3) point

```
DX = X1 + X2 - 2 * X3
DY = Y1 + Y2 - 2 * Y3
Len = Sqrt(DX * DX + DY * DY)
RedX = X3 + d3 * DX / Len
RedY = Y3 + d3 * DY / Len
```